# Roots of derivative of function

Tags: functions

If I have an information that roots of a function are real , on what basis can I say that the roots of its derivative are real and distinct?

Comment: You can't. When you write *function*, do you mean *polynomial*? You can say more in that case.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Or just _differentiable function_. I think that's all you need as MVT says everything you can say if all you're given are the roots.